# Three table conditional query - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have three tables.

User

```
________________________________________________
|User_ID | User Name | user contact information|
------------------------------------------------
```

School

```
________________________________________________________________
|School_ID | School name | school address | school contact info|
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Picture

```
___________________________________________
| Picture ID | User_ID | School_ID|file path|
-------------------------------------------
```

Per School_ID, I want to display information as follows.

School name, school address, User name, user contact information, and all the pictures that has matching school ID.

What would the script be in php. 
I have researched couple days on this website, and tried many codes, but nothing has worked so far.

Here is the code I have used.

```
<?php
         $sql="SELECT Schoolname, School_contact_info, email, description, address, website, file, userName FROM school, picture, user WHERE Location_ID=Picture_ID  ORDER BY Location_ID desc";
         $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
         {
          ?>
                <div href=<?php $row['Location_ID'] ?>>
                <td><?php echo $row['Location_ID'] ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row['name2'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                <div><td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td></div>
                </div>

                <div><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'];?>" alt=" " height="75" width="75"></div>

                <br>
                <?php
         }
     ?>
```

I want to display school information, and all the pictures that has school_ID as foreign key.

Comment: `and tried many codes` ... what did you try and could you please include that?  Asking for a full PHP script with a query is too broad for a single question I think.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen , this question will not be well received without demonstrating some own efforts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question with the code I have used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Query to should use

```
select school_name,school_address,user_name,user_contact_information
from user,school,picture where user.user_id=picture_id 
and school.school_id=picture.picture_id

    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // Perform queries 
    mysqli_query($con,"select school_name,school_address,user_name,user_contact_information
    from user,school,picture where user.user_id=picture_id 
    and school.school_id=picture.picture_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

In you table structure you are not given all the column details those you are using in the query.
But try this :-

```
SELECT s.Schoolname, s.School_contact_info, s.email, s.description, s.address, s.website,
 p.file, u.userName 
FROM school as s,
 picture as p on s.School_ID=p.School_ID, 
 user as u on p.User_ID=u.User_ID
WHERE s.Location_ID=p.Picture_ID  ORDER BY s.Location_ID desc
```

I am assuming that columns like `Location_ID,email,website` are from school table .